# How to use Exception Handling to throw Exception when input is not an int ; in Java?

Tags: java, exception, integer, illegalargumentexception

Here is what i've done so far:

```
 public static int stringToInt(String str) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    int number = 0;


    try{
        number = Integer.parseInt(str);

    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("Invalid Integer");
        //throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        System.out.println("Invalid Integer");
    }//finally{
      return number;    
    //}

 }
```

How can i throw the exception if the string is not an Integer without return an argument like [null]?

Comment: Don't catch IllegalArgumentException -- ***throw it*** from within your NumberFormatException catch block

Comment: Remove the try block and the catch blocks. Integer.parseInt() *already* throws an exception if the string doesn't represent an integer. Don't catch it, and it will be propagated.

Comment: Agree with JB Nizet, I strongly discourage catching runtime exceptions in most cases

Comment: Typing exactly was @JBNizet was saying. You can catch and rethrow NFE.

Comment: We have to use these blocks , it's an exercise from an university server. If i didnt use them, the compiler give errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, that's the solution:

```
public static int stringToInt(String str) throws IllegalArgumentException {
int number = 0;
try{
    number = Integer.parseInt(str);
    return number;  
}catch (NumberFormatException e){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid integer");
}}
```

I learn Exception Handling right now and think i understand a little bit more. :'D